# Ruby : Array of single type elements

Tags: ruby, arrays

Is there a way in Ruby to create an Array of elements that **are** of the same type?

Ex:

```
class User
end

my_array = UserArray.new
```

I could certainly create the class manually, but I'd rather have a default behavior since I could need it for many different classes.

Thanks

Comment: Why do you need the class? Why not `my_array = []`, `my_array << User.new` ?

Comment: @falsetru I guess, he wants to restrict array to use the specific elements, like collection...

Comment: If you want something like what generics are in Java, Ruby does not support that. You'd need to implement it yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean by **are**? Simply *are*? Like this?

```
class User; end
my_array = 5.times.map { User.new }
```

Or *must be*? Like this?

```
class << Array
  def of klass_in_plural
    require 'active_support/inflector'    # gem install activesupport if necessary
    klass = const_get klass_in_plural.to_s.singularize
    Class.new self do
      define_method :check do
        require 'y_support/typing'        # gem install y_support if necessary
        aT_all_kind_of klass              # runtime assertion that raises TypeError unless
      end                                 # all the elements of self are #kind_of? klass

      class << self
        def [] *args; super.check end
        def new *args; super.check end
      end

      def << arg; super.check end
      def + arg; self.class.new super end
      def - arg; self.class.new super end
      # etc etc
    end
  end
end

a = Array.of( :Integers )[ 1, 2, 3 ]
#=> [ 1, 2, 3 ]
b = Array.of( :Integers )[ 1, 2, 3.3 ]
#=> TypeError: Each collection element must be kind of Integer!
c = Array.of( :Hashes )[ { a: 42 } ]
#=> [{a: 42}]
d = Array.of( :Hashes )[ 42 ]
#=> TypeError: Each collection element must be kind of Hash!
e = Array.of( :Users )[ User.new, User.new ]
#=> [#<User:0xb7cd8040>, #<User:0xb7cdaa0c>]
```

Comment: @Jeffery, the second section of my code was a bit tricky and I had to test it before posting it live.

Comment: Yeah well, what you call "the first part" was really a comment.

Comment: `Array.new(3,"12")` will create an array of 3 `"12"` objects, which will hold same objects right? Is this can't be the answer, why such more code? Or may be I didn't get the point of OP's.

Comment: @ArupRakshit, hats off to you, you taught me more about `Array.new` syntax. But, I have a comeback ready, `a = Array.new 3, "12"` creates and array of 3 *same* instances, so that `a[0] << "3"; a` results in unexpected `["123", "123", "123"]`. As for the second section, it actually, as a newly formed expert like you must know by now, it constructs an `Array` parametrized subclass, that performs type checking on its elements, enforcing their type compliance.

Comment: @BorisStitnicky Humm!! Good! :) Question was a bit complex o me. One more thing `Array.new(4) { "12" }`, will create 4 different `"12"` objects in the `Array`.

Comment: @ArupRakshit, `Array.new 3 do "12" end` does the trick, I found :-)

Comment: @BorisStitnicky Yes.. I just wrote you the same.

Answer (score 1):

I will be adding one more answer, one that does not address the literal OP question, but solves the problem that the asker probably has. Major classes of `User` type often have their instances kept in some sort of civil registry. That is, one or more collection exist in the object space with user names and possibly other kinds of IDs, that can all be used to uniquely identify `User` instances. We are then concerned about validating whether an object is a user, or a user id, or not. This situation is encountered so often, that at least for the naming part, I have written a gem, `y_support/name_magic`. This gem is inspired by the fact that classes and modules in Ruby are often named, that they can be named by constant assignment, and even have built-in `#name` method returning their name. Install `name_magic` with `gem install y_support` and use it as follows:

```
require 'y_support/name_magic'

class User
  include NameMagic
  def to_s; "user #{name or object_id}" end
  def inspect; "#<#{self}>" end
end

# we can now construct named users easily:
u = User.new name: "Cathy"
u.name #=> :Cathy
User::Cathy #=> #<user Cathy>
# and we also have constant magic at our disposal to construct named users:
Fred = User.new #=> #<user Fred>
# By including NameMagic, User class has acquired the registry of instances:
User.instances #=> [#<user Cathy>, #<user Fred>]
# And the ability to indifferently access those instances by their ids:
User.instance( u ) #=> #<user Cathy>
User.instance( :Cathy ) #=> #<user Cathy>
User.instance( "Fred" ) #=> #<user Fred>
User.instance( :Augustin ) #=> NameError: No instance Augustin in User.
# Anonymous users can be constructed, too:
u = User.new
# And named later
u.name = "Joe"
# We can notice that although user "Cathy" is no longer explicitly assigned
# to any variable (since u contains Joe now), it is still registered in the
# @instances instance variable owned by User class and serviced by NameMagic
# mixin. So Cathy continues to live as a User instance:
User.instances #=> [#<user Cathy>, #<user Fred>, #<user Joe>]
# If we wanted Cathy garbage collected, we would have to forget her explicitly
User.forget :Cathy # returns the unnamed user Cathy for the last time
User::Cathy #=> NameError: uninitialized constant User::Cathy
```

And at this point, I usually define a constructor `#User` so that I don't have to type "`.new`" over and over:

```
def User *args, &block
  User.new *args, &block
end
```

And an instance accessor `#user`, so that I don't have to type "`User.instance`" over and over:

```
def user user
  User.instance user
end
```

Afterwards, I'm equipped to deal with the problems of instance identification and class validation:

```
# Constructing new users:
User name: "Augustin" #=> #<user Augustin>
Quentin = User() #=> #<user Quentin>
# () is necessary to distinguish the method #User from the constant User

user :Quentin #=> #<user Quentin>
user :Arun #=> NameError: No instance Arun in User.

# I will subclass Array to define an array of users:
class Users < Array
  class << self
    def [] *args; super *args.map { |arg| user arg } end
    def new arg; super arg.map { |e| user e } end
  end
end

# And I will define conveninece constructors #Users and #users:
def Users arg; Users.new arg end
def users *args; Users[ *args ] end

# Now I have indifferent access regardless whether the elements are instances or
# instance ids (ie. names):
Users [ Fred, :Augustin ] #=> [#<user Fred>, #<user Augustin>]
# And I validate that the collection elements must be User instances or their ids:
users :Augustin, :Quentin #=> [#<user Augustin>, #<user Quentin>]
users :Augustin, :Arun # NameError: No instance Arun in User.
```

To finish the tour, let us review the instances we have created and notice the method `Array#names` also defined by `name_magic`:

```
users = User.instances
#=> [#<user Fred>, #<user Joe>, #<user Augustin>, #<user Quentin>]

user_names = users.names
#=> [:Fred, :Joe, :Augustin, :Quentin]
```